# How to remove left character in strings of unequal length

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to convert text to values.

I assume the "value" function doesn't work because of the "$" as the first character in the strings.

I'm stuck on how to trim it. Because the strings are of different lengths, the "right" function won't work.

It seems there should be a simple solution to this but I can't find it.

Data looks like this:

```
$9964.38
$10123.45
and so forth
```

Comment: "Data looks like this"... so is it formatted with a dollar sign in front? Is it a text format with $ symbol?

Answer (score 2):

Use MID and start with the 2nd character:

```
=MID(A1,2,LEN(A1))
```

Comment: For efficiency to save calculating the LEN, I would just use MID(A1,2,99) or ,999) or ,9999) depending on the expected data for this scenario. Basically "longer than I ever expect to see". (no need to go mad since Excel won't permit 99999999 characters in a cell anyway)

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUBSTITUTE() to remove `$` character, like this:

`=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"$",""))`

Answer (score 0):

Please check these.
Extract all characters except the first character：

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)
```

Extract all characters except the last character：

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)
```